# I want to save file on server directory without prompt screen

Tags: php, html, spreadsheet, xls

A spreadsheet is generated when I submit a form. A prompt is appear which ask me to save file, but I want that when I submit form that spreadsheet automatically saved in my server directory e.g. `public_html/apm/test/file.xls.`

How can I handle this.

Previously I am using this **code**

```
    /* Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header. */

    $data = array(
        array("firstname" => $firstName, "lastname" => $lastName, "age" => $phoneNo, "email" => $email, "dob" => $dob, "mailingAddress" => $mailingAddress, "prescribedPhysician" => $prescribedPhysician, "patientID" => $patientID, "caregiver" => $caregiver, "nameOfCaregiver" => $nameOfCaregiver, "growLocation" => $growLocation, "expirationDate" => $expirationDate, "registrationNo" => $registrationNo, "medicalCondition" => $medicalCondition, "describeMedicalCondition" => $describeMedicalCondition, "grower" => $grower, "tradingCannabis" => $tradingCannabis, "medicalCannabis" => $medicalCannabis, "needCaregiver" => $needCaregiver)
    );

    function cleanData(&$str){
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"'))
            $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    // file name for download

    $filename = $firstName." ".$lastName." ".date('d-m-y') . ".xls";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    foreach($data as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $flag = true;
        }

        array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
    }

    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing exactly what you tell it to do: "make this content downloadable for the web client.". This is done by both [`header` directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-examples):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Then, at the end of the code, you're `echo`ing some content. So this content is served to the user

If you want to save the file on the server, you can't echo the file content, but you have to *save* this content on the server. You can do it using [`file_put_contents` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).